# Show data table from JSON in iPad app

Tags: ios, json, ipad

I have a API which returns JSON:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "A green door",
    "price": 12.50,
    "tags": ["home", "green"]
}

{
    "id": 2,
    "name": "A blue door",
    "price": 13.50,
    "tags": ["work", "blue"]
}
```

In iPad app, I need to show this in the following data table format:

```
id    name          price     tags
1     A green door  12.50     home, green
2     A blue door   13.50     work, blue
```

I have tried the following https://github.com/brightec/CustomCollectionViewLayout but it does not work.

How can it be done?

Comment: https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?q=table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a simple table view. I created a simple example with your data. Sorry, I don't have time to add comments and the UI is basic.
Check the following example:
[Show data into table view](https://github.com/juansftdev/ShowDataIntoTableView)